# Return a filename, but with wildcards resolved

Tags: python

I have a directory structure like this`F:\CodeSnippets\File1.test.4.7009.zip`

I tried this:

```
head, tail=os.path.split('F:\CodeSnippets\File1.test.4.*.zip')
print (tail)
```

which prints `File1.test.4.*.zip`, but I want the full name with wildcards resolved.

`os.path.basename('F:\CodeSnippets\File1.test.4.*.zip')`
also returns `File1.test.4.*.zip`.

What else can i try?

Comment: What if it resolves (matches) more than one file?

Comment: Try [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Comment: True, I actually one number that is 4 in 'File1.test.4.*.zip' just need to find 7009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives you all the filenames matching the wildcard

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('F:\CodeSnippets\File1.test.*.*.zip')
print(files)
```

Note: `glob` returns the full match, including the path.

See the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for further details and options

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a list of files in the directory, and then perform a RegEx match to determine which files match the wildcards.

Comment: Too many files in that directory, it will take a long time to populate.